# Idiomatic French expressions for "That's what does it for me"

Tags: expressions

> Vous veillez sur nous en permanence. Il n’y a que quelqu'un de vraiment gentil pour en faire autant. ***That's what does it for me.***

This colloquial English expression means:

> = *That's what pleases / impresses / inspires etc me (about you).*
>
> = **C'est ça qui me plaît** (en vous).

I came across the following three phrases, but I’m not sure if they really capture the meaning of the original English expression.

> 1: Ça me **branche**.
>
> 2 : Ça me **botte**.
>
> 3 : Ça m'**interpelle**.

Comment: Sorry, but That's what IT does for me and That's what YOU do for me are not the same thing at all. /That's what IT does for me/ has to refer to an activity or thing. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Lambie Hi. I'm afraid I fail to see your point here... "That's what **does it** for me {= That's what **pleases/impresses/inspires/etc** me}" is the very expression that I want to use here. And it is an entirely different expression from saying "That's what **it does / you do** for me". Your phrase is used completely differently: "Cleaning my room – that's what **it{this robot} does / you do** for me".

Comment: For example (in Line 8): http://www.capitalgazette.com/neighborhoods/ph-ac-gn-glen-burnie-east-0520-20150518-story.html

Comment: OK, I get it now: That's what does it for me. Yes, I misread  your question. Sorry.

Comment: Here is my issue: You say that /That's what does it for me/ ***means*** That's what I like about you. That's not correct at all so my objection is correct. That's what DOES IT for me means: That's what turns me on OR That's what satisfies me (some desire I have). That's what DOES IT FOR ME, does mean: Cela me branche.

Comment: Beware of matching the langage levels - you couldn't say "Vous veillez sur nous en permanence. Il n’y a que quelqu'un de vraiment gentil pour en faire autant. Ça me branche.". The last sentence is a different language register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "**That's what does it for me**"

word by word translates to:

> *C'est ça qui le fait pour moi.*

This resemble the French casual expression:

> *Ça le fait* → It is properly/well done, it is the right way

but it is not exactly what the English one means.

Your translation is quite good, and likely the one I would have suggested too:

> ***C'est ça qui me plaît.***

All three alternatives you found have issues:

> *Ça me branche* → "I'm interested about doing something (in the future)."
>
> *Ça me botte* → "I like it a lot" but very outdated.
>
> *Ça m'interpelle* → Frowned upon, "I'm concerned about it; I feel the need to react."

Other suggestions can be:

> - ***C'est (ça) mon trip***. colloquial but doesn't work when followed by "chez toi".
> - ***C'est (ça) mon truc***. common, same issue with *chez toi*.
> - ***C'est ça que je kiffe***. This is *banlieues* slang going mainstream but it isn't usable by everyone and far too colloquial.

Note that your introduction is too formal French to be followed by anything colloquial. To stay in the tone, that would be:

> *Vous veillez sur nous en permanence. Il n’y a que quelqu'un de vraiment gentil pour en faire autant. **C'est ce que j'apprécie particulièrement chez vous.***

Comment: Duh. I was wondering whether it should be *tutoies* and *vouvoies* since you conjugate French verbs in English :-) Or… perhaps *tutoyez* and *vovoyez*? Errr.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Yes, trying to mix French conjugated verbs with English was a failure, fixed. Thanks !

Comment: "c'est **ça** qui" suggests the person you are talking to already know you like her/him, whereas "c'est **ce** qui" doesn't have this meaning. To me at least.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Yes, that's an interesting nuance and I agree with you about it.

Comment: Surfing really does IT for me. Skiing really does it for me veut bien dire: Faire du surf me branche.

Comment: @jlliagre Surfing really does IT for me. Skiing really does it for me veut bien dire: Faire du surf me branche. Je pense que That what does it for me veut bien dire: X me branche. X me satisfait (pas très jolie) mais c'est ça que l'expression veut dire. Il y avait un malentendu pour l'anglais dans la question....

Comment: @Lambie Je pense aussi qu'il y a une erreur d'interprétation dans la question. J'ai modifié ma réponse pour prendre en compte cette éventualité.

Comment: Indeed, jlliagre! As you have pointed out, "That's what I like" (without "about you") is the correct interpretation. I initially added the words "about you / en vous" solely in light of the context of the example, to make the meaning clearer. Apologies for the confusion! I should have stuck to the literal translation. The correct meaning is as shown in bold in my 1st comment. Merci.

Comment: Hi. I'm curious about what makes the first two sentences sound so formal. Is it simply due to the presence of "vous", or the choice of words such as "veiller sur" and "en permanence"?

Comment: By the way, those three phrases I listed seems to have been suggested by a native French speaker. So he/she might have misinterpreted the meaning of the original English expression in the first place.

Comment: "**Vous**", "**veillez sur**", "**en permanence**", and "**en faire autant**" are all more or less formal. If you can explain the context of this sentence and who are the people involved, I might try to reformulate it in casual or colloquial French. About the three phrases, that person has indeed likely missed the meaning, or might has just provided expressions similar to the previously answered ones. The fact "*ça me botte*" is suggested might be also due a regionalism. I see it more than I would have expected by googling discussion forums.

Answer (score 3):

Your translation of the meaning:

> C'est ça qui me plaît en vous.

is actually more appropriate than the other suggestions you make. You could, however, change it a bit like this:

> C'est ce qui me plaît en vous.

Using *"ça"* puts a lot of emphasis on the object (the fact he/she is watching over you): it's like saying *"It is that thing, that I like about you"*. On the other hand, using *"ce"* puts more emphasis on the *"vous"* at the end of the sentence: it is like saying *"This is what makes me like you"*. Using *"ce"* also feels a bit more natural.

You could shorten without ambiguity it by using just:

> C'est ce qui me plaît.

This gives much more importance to the *"plaît"* word, and produces more impact, overall.

Regarding your suggestions, I fully agree with jlliagre. The first two are quite outdated, and none of them would fit well.

Comment: Je dirais plus "*chez vous*" que "*en vous*"

Comment: Je trouve que le "en vous" a une connotation plus intime. Pour exagérer, "chez vous" penche plus dans le registre de la plaisanterie que dans la déclaration d'amour. Mais les deux sont corrects, en effet.

Comment: "C'est ce qui me plait" feels a lot more correct than "C'est ça qui me plaît en vous.". Maybe it's just a matter of taste. That "ça qui" does not quite feel right to my French ear. "C'est ce qui" sounds a lot better to me.

Comment: @Frank I agree, especially when written. But it is still correct, and if you imagine it spoken, with a lot of emphasis on the "ça", it makes sense. The intent is a bit different, though.

Comment: @dim - yes, it is correct, absolutely... when speaking :-)

Answer (score 0):

Contemporary and idiomatic? Just the simple word "**cool**". But, like some of the suggestions above that wouldn't mesh with the OP's example too well:

> Vous veillez sur nous en permanence. Il n’y a que quelqu'un de vraiment gentil pour en faire autant. C'est ca que je kiffe.

No, you couldn't say that IMHO, the language register/level is not the same.